# Can I create cloudshell shell without driver?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, quali-cloudshell

I would like to build a quali cloudshell shell with driver. I.e. just a data model without python driver.
Can I do that when working with shellfoundry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a CloudShell Shell without a driver whether using ShellFoundry or not.

In order to remove the driver from being attached to the Model of the Shell, open **shellconfig.xml** file located under **datamodel** directory for editing.

Then remove **Driver** attribute from the **ResourceTemplate** XML node:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ShellsConfiguration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.qualisystems.com/ResourceManagement/ShellsConfigurationSchema.xsd">
<ResourceTemplates>
    <ResourceTemplate Name="ShellWithoutDriver" Model="ShellWithoutDriver">
        <Description></Description>
        <AutoLoad Enable="false">
            <Description>Description for autoload </Description>
        </AutoLoad>
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute Name="User" Value="" />
            <Attribute Name="Password" Value="" />
        </Attributes>
    </ResourceTemplate>    
</ResourceTemplates>
</ShellsConfiguration>
```